# MAC OS genymotion device not show in list deployt of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, genymotion

I use Mac OS 10.10, with genymotion 2.2.2 and virtual box 4.3. When I create ADV in eclipse to run app. It show normally in list deploy, but genymotion. although I ran it already, config setting...
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in eclipse - OSX yosemite, what you need to do is in the Android Device Chooser Window, try to RESIZE THE SERIAL NUMBER TAB and you will see the genymotion emulator that is running

If you don't see it, or the Android Device Chooser Window doesn't appear, check three things before running again:

Developer Options is enabled from settings (by repeated touching 7 times the build number in about phone), even though developer options is available in the list of apps in genymotion emulator
In Settings>Security, make sure "Unknown Sources" is enabled
Go to Run Configuration (for Android app), select the Target Tab, Enable Always prompt to pick device and hit apply.
Additionally I downloaded the jar files from Genymotion Download Page manually and replaced it in the plugin folder of eclipse.

Source: [Genymotion devices not working in Eclipse on OS X Yosemite [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158118/genymotion-devices-not-working-in-eclipse-on-os-x-yosemite-solved/26347617#26347617)

Comment: thanks you for exactly right answer, ... but too late. I sold my macbook and use window OS :(