# Genymotion devices not working in Eclipse on OS X Yosemite

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, virtualbox, genymotion

I updated from Mavericks to Yosemite and now I can't use any Genymotion device anymore.
You can see the devices in Eclipse, but when you want to run an application you can't select one of these devices.


I've already re-installed Eclipse, Genymotion and Virtualbox...

The Genymotion Virtual Devices Manager shows a Nexus 5 which is stated 'On'
[image: Genymotion Virtual Devices Manager shows an Nexus 5 and the stat is 'On']


When I want to run my application, there is no Nexus 5..
[image: Android Device Chooser doesn't show the Nexus 5]

Comment: I think your adb is doing problem are other device is working i mean external devices

Comment: I don't have an Android device..

Comment: Then try to use default emulator

Comment: I'm a student and we have to use Genymotion at school

Comment: my default emulator doesn't work either.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**This is a bug in eclipse - OSX yosemite, what you need to do is in the Android Device Chooser Window, try to RESIZE THE SERIAL NUMBER TAB and you will see the genymotion emulator that is running**

If you don't see it, or the Android Device Chooser Window doesn't appear, check three things before running again:

1. Developer Options is enabled from settings (by repeated touching 7
   times the build number in about phone), even though developer
   options is available in the list of apps in genymotion emulator
2. In Settings>Security, make sure "Unknown Sources" is enabled
3. Go to Run Configuration (for Android app), select the Target Tab, Enable Always prompt to pick device and hit apply.

Additionally I downloaded the jar files from [Genymotion Download Page](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/) manually and replaced it in the plugin folder of eclipse.

**EDIT**

FYI, a bug has been opened in AOSP's issue tracker.

[Issue 78436: [ADT/Eclipse] Cannot see my device in the Android Device Chooser dialog even though it is there in the Devices view](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78436&q=device%20chooser&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

At bottom of this page, there is a link to **'Vote for this issue'** ...

Comment: This must be a bug with Yosemite/Eclipse. It worked fine before I upgraded to Yosemite. This is a great answer, as the solution is nonsensical

Comment: ya, initially i too thought something went amiss after the upgrade, but genymotion running fine in android studio made me look around.

Comment: RESIZE THE SERIAL NUMBER TAB!

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Thanks!!! I was going to reinstall my eclipse, but your answer just saved me!

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Thanks. I had the same problem since I upgrade to Yosemite. Android device choose window behave in the same way with all devices including third party emulators. I kept reconnecting my device and changing the cables. you have solved a big problem and I did not even think about it.

Comment: Not so obisous so I comment, RESIZe the SeRIAL NUMBER TAB and it's appearing… strange that I have this issue only with Genymotion devices.

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve this problem by connect a real device one time.

Answer (score 0):

Please scroll down and see list of devices which is connected to ADB.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my problem was that the emulated device was running Android 4.3 (SDK version 18), but the app had `android:minSdkVersion="19"` so since no compatible device was found the list was empty.

Double check your emulated device version, and the `minSdkVersion` number, to make sure it's compatible.