# Eclipse + adb - Have to restart adb to get emulator to show up in device chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb

this problem just started happening about a week ago, and i can't seem to determine what the cause is so i'm hoping someone else might be able to give some ideas.

the emulator starts up and can be seen in the DDMS view and `adb devices` displays the emulator when run from the command line. however, when i try to launch my app, the Android Device Chooser dialog doesn't show it in the "Choose a running Android device" list until i forcibly restart adb. this must be done each time the app is (re-)launched.

Eclipse and adb are both running as my Linux user.

some details about my setup:

- OS X Yosemite
- Eclipse Luna
- ADT 23.0.4.1468518

... i *think* this may have started after i upgraded from OS X Mavericks => Yosemite, but that might be a red herring.

any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! it's a nuisance that feels like it saps a little bit of productivity.

** **UPDATE (solved)** **

after a whole lot of searching and coming up empty-handed, i decided to go the route of trying out Genymotion (which, incidentally, seems great!). i ended up looking to resolve a problem related that setup, which ultimately lead me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158118/genymotion-devices-not-working-in-eclipse-on-os-x-yosemite). there's apparently a bug that was introduced/activated for Mac users who have upgraded to Yosemite that causes running emulators not to be shown in the Android Device Chooser dialog.

as mentioned in the referred post by @Anwar Ul Islam, the remedy is to simply **resize the serial number tab**, which i guess forces the window to redraw, and the device to magically appear.

now i'm able to see any running emulators, be it the one shipped with the SDK or Genymotion.

Comment: wow resizing the tab still fixes the bug, on a clean install of Yosemite. wow